# What causes Windows 10 to hang at the Shutting Down Screen? My on/off button won't turn my pc off.

Tags: shutdown

I tried shutting down my pc last night. It hung at the shutting down screen. My On/Off button would not shut it off. I had to turn off the surge strip to turn it off. Any solutions to this strange problem? I have a Dell Inspiron. I have a Pentium Dual Core. 6 gigs of Ram. Any suggestions?

Comment: How long was it hung during shut down?  Were you just pressing the on/off button? Or were you holding it down for ~5 seconds to force it off?

Comment: Check Event Viewer, also Disable fast startup: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue, try modifying this shutdown setting: `Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Choose what the power buttons do`. Near the bottom there should be `Turn on fast startup (recommended)`, uncheck this box and click `Save Changes`. Now restart your laptop to be sure it shuts down properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and managed to solve it by changing the power plan to "high performance". When in "balanced", the system will stop in the output screen. Moreover, create a custom plan and change the options in "Power Options> Choose what the power button does." In some cases, you will have to disable the "fast boot".

Answer (score 0):

My win10 hung on shutdown while I was asleep. So hung like that all night. As when I woke, I had a blue screen and spinning white dots and ''shutting down'' still on screen. I long pressed the power button (which, of course, was still lit) and it powered-off by that means instead.

HOWEVER, I already, and still do have all of my power settings as above. I have to, being an audio recording type of guy.
If I don't optimze power, Windows becomes irritating in defualt.(For my purposes, this means that If I use fast strart-up, and various power save options, I'm in danger of peripheral devices, or, USB devices, being powered off while using them, duhhhh!

SO I'm guessing something is being missed above?
And that that something may be a disk issue? (Bad sector/s perhaps?)
So, I'll try some form of disk check/fix and post my results here later today.

EDIT:
Well, it is now ''later today'', and loaded up Powershell (copy and paste ''powershell'' into start menu search, right-click and run as admin).
Typed in > Repair-Volume C –Scan <   (don't copy the > < symbols).
And nothing appears to be wrong there. Nothing found, YET, at same time I notice in notifications beside date/time on task bar ''restart to repair drive errors. Click to restart you PC''

SO which is right?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).